# Searching text and use setFindListener for a webView

Tags: android

I want to searching a text Inside WebView.
when searching end .
If the text inside webView : Tosat "yes";
If not Toast "No".
I use below code:

```
      int API = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if(API < 16) {
    DeleteAccount.web.findAll("Sorry, too many tries");
    }
else {
    DeleteAccount.web.findAllAsync("Sorry, too many tries");
    }
DeleteAccount. web.setFindListener(new FindListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFindResultReceived(int activeMatchOrdinal, int number_match, boolean isDoneCounting) {

        if(number_match!=0)
              Toast.makeText(base_context, "yes", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        else 
  //....

    });
```

but when give error :

```
      11-22 15:11:59.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2215): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   11-22 15:11:59.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2215):    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.doctortelegram.MyTimer$2
```

I think the Does not understand below methods in API 16

```
   web.setFindListener....
```